# Too many connections to postgresql heroku with spring

Tags: spring, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have **hobby-dev** plan PostgreSQL database on **Heroku** and my Spring application that don't use this database. When I deploy my code Heroku say me, that I use **10 database connections of 20**. Can you explain why? None of configuration changes from [heroku example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) help me. My test-server do absolutely nothing but hold this connections... Should i write custom Spring config and if I should, how can I do it?

This is my Controller class code, by the way, `application.properties` is empty.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public RedirectView redirect() {
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
        redirectView.setUrl("https://google.com/");
        return redirectView;
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026422/default-maximumpoolsize-for-hikaricp

Comment: @sonus21 Really, It helped me... You are the best))